# How to set key listeners to function in a specific pane in a JSplitPane done to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, keylistener, jsplitpane

I currently have a JFrame that I split up into three JSplitPanes (one splitting vertically down the middle and the left pane of that has a horizontal split).  I have a functional game in the left pane which works fine when run by itself in its own JFrame, but when put into the JSplitPane, the action listeners on the keys do not work on the game but my space bar does function as pressing the start button in another pane.

Below I am posting the section of the code that deals with the split panes.  My question is, is there a way to make it so the key listeners on the game work?  Also is there a way to keep the start button listener working while also keeping the game working but switch the function for the button to be activated when you press 'r' instead of the space bar?

(Quick rundown of the variables in the code.  The 'board' is actually a new instance of the game being activated in another class, it paints the board and begins the game when you press the start button.  'GameTable' is the JPanel on the left side that holds the start button and a quick title.  'Statistics' just holds some non-interactive things like scores and high scores.)

```
//Creates a new game and assigns it to the GameTable JPanel
    GameTable.add(board, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    /* NOTE:
     * The Vertical and Horizontal SplitPanes are flipped.
     * The GameTableHorizontal uses the JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT function but splits horizontally
     * The opposite is true for the VerticalSplitPane
     * The cause for this is still unknown
     */

    //Adds GameTable JPanel and board to GameTableHorizontal SplitPane and adds that to JFrame
    GameTableHorizontal = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, true, GameTable, board);
    GameTableHorizontal.setDividerLocation(50);
    GameTableHorizontal.setEnabled(false);
    this.add(GameTableHorizontal);

    //Adds GameTableHorizontal and Statistics JPanels to VerticalSplitPane and adds that to JFrame
    VerticalSplitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, true, GameTableHorizontal, Statistics);
    VerticalSplitPane.setDividerLocation(xPos/2);
    VerticalSplitPane.setEnabled(false);
    this.add(VerticalSplitPane);

    //Creates a start button and assigns an ActionListener to it
    Start = new JButton("Start");
    StartListener actionStart = new StartListener();
    Start.addActionListener(actionStart);
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow [Java Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Incorrect naming conventions messes up the highlighting of the code posted on the forum.

> is, is there a way to make it so the key listeners on the game work?

Don't use KeyListeners. The problem is likely because your game panel doesn't have focus.

Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). When using `Key Bindings` you can bind a `KeyStroke` to an `Action`. The Action can still be invoked even if the components doesn't have focus.

You can search the forum for lots of examples using key bindings. Or you can check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for comparison code between using the two approaches. Its complete with working examples of both approaches.